# What is the best tool to add a GUI to Python code and make a Linux application from it?

Tags: python, gui, programming

I am learning Python. What is the best tool to add a GUI to Python code and make a Linux application from it? Something that is easy to learn but powerful. I found something like PyGTK, Tkinter or PyGObject. What do you recommend?

Comment: I find tkinter the easiest for folks without programming experience, but it's still not easy. GUIs tools are *not* easy to learn...the computer's view of a GUI is very different from a human's view. All three are powerful. Advice: Look up a simple online tutorial for each, and try each one.

Comment: Ubuntu comes preinstalled with `zenity` command. It allows making simple popup dialogs. If that's sufficient for you, see an example of how it can be done in one of my apps: https://github.com/SergKolo/udisks-indicator/blob/97c737dde7e537dc0cd1ba09342f0b90fd431af6/udisks-indicator#L526 Otherwise, if you seek full GUI with windows, widgets, etc, then probably TKinter is the simplest for starters. Also please note, that by asking "what is the best x" your question is primarily opinion-based and makes it off-topic on the site

Comment: Links: [How can I create a directly-executable cross-platform GUI app using Python? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2933/4518341), [How to write GUI in Python? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2310130/4518341), [GUI Programming - Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming), [Graphic User Interface FAQ - Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/gui.html)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what you found, WxPython is quite easy for beginners.
Is open-source, quite easy to install in ubunutu:

`apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8`

and has lots of tutorials:

http://zetcode.com/wxpython/